# How do I add a separator in a grid in wxPython?

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I've been trying to add separator lines between rows in my grid. I tried using **wx.Menu()** with the **AppendSeparator()** method, however the wx grid can't add objects of type Menu. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by the grid widget. You could size a column or row such that it is skinnier than usual and change all the cells in that row or column to have a different background color. You might also be able to utilize a custom label renderer or cell renderer. See the wxPython demo for examples.